# Safari bug - input:checked with two labels controlling it

Tags: html, css, safari

I've got a toggle on a web site I'm developing using input:checked and a label as the toggle.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="expand-services" class="services">
<label class="expand-services" for="expand-services">
      <img src="img/icon-expand-services.png" alt="">
</label>
```

And in an unordered list below:

```
<li><label for="expand-services">SERVICES</label></li>
```

CSS:

```
div.services {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
    background: url("../img/bg-services.png") repeat;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

input.services:checked ~ div.services {
    height: 125px;
}

input.services:checked ~ label img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);  
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

So this works great in every browser as its supposed to. Clicking either label checks (or unchecks) the hidden checkbox, and changes the height of div.services to 125px, or to 0px, depending, and rotates the label img (a simple arrow) from pointing up to pointing down.

Only, in Safari, when I click one of the labels, it works great. As long as I stick to that label. If I click the other label afterwards, only the img gets rotated. The height of div.services is no longer affected, even if I click that original label again after. Every other browser, both labels work great. See the images below as a reference.

Hope my problem makes sense.

Image reference for this:

[image]

[image]

Any idea where I've flopped?

Comment: If it helps, everything works just fine if I remove one label or the other. But as soon as both labels are there controlling the same input, stuff goes awry in Safari.

Comment: Also if it helps... this only appears to be an issue with Safari 5.1.7 for windows. From the versions I've tested on my iMac, it works just fine there.

Comment: Found the fix - for those that unlikely run into the same issue, it's because for whatever reason Safara 5.1.7 does not like having a css transition and visibility: declared on the same element. I had used the two in combination on the drop-up menus below the services box in the pictures, and that cascaded into issues in Safari with the services menu too. Once I moved Visibility to a LTE I9 stylesheet, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If Safari windows is a problem, you might try to use a single `label` and produce a pseudo-element from it.

You need to tune a few things with a different approach, like using `inherits` value to apply transition on a pseudo element to fix another bug of Safari

test this codepen and see if it is worth to use some parts of it: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LKqJF

Answer (score 0):

That should help :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="expand-services" class="services">
<div class="fuck-safari">
 <label class="expand-services" for="expand-services"></label>
 <img src="img/icon-expand-services.png" alt="">
</div>
```

I have the same problem in IE.